# azure storage tables and best performance/value

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I was wondering which of the following two archititchers would have higher performance/value?

Having THREE tables with the following structure:

```
1 - Users table 
[userid(as primarykey), pass(as Rowkey), phone_number]
2 - Sports
[userid(as primarykey), sportid(as Rowkey), sport_name]
3 - Games
[sportid(as primarykey), gameid(as Rowkey), game_date]
```

Or having ONE table with the following structure:

```
[userid(as primarykey), (Sport or Game as text)(as Rowkey), sport_name or game_date]
```

Or maybe there is even better solution/idea for this data structure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you going to query the data? Considering Azure Tables have limited indexing support, your architecture/design will depend a lot on that. Also, not sure if you have already read it but do read this guide from Storage team: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/.

Comment: This is really broad, with no right answer, and off-topic for StackOverflow. As @GauravMantri already mentioned, this is dependent on your app, and your query needs. You could end up with lots of partition/table scans if you have just one table and need to search for properties outside of the partition/row key. Not sure how you're defining *value* - if it's cost / GB, only you can determine  that, based on your storage needs.